# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate for value less than other value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to figure out the right syntax to update (increment) a value by 1 if one value is smaller than another. Here's some more details:

**Data Structure**

```
{
    "currentTask": 0,
    "maximumTask":10
}
```

**What I want to do**

1. If there is a document where `currentTask < maximumTask`
2. Retrieve that document
3. Increment the `currentTask` value by 1

**What I tried**

```
let solver = await solvers.findOneAndUpdate({"currentTask":{"$lt": "$maximumTask"}},{"$inc":{"currentTask":1}});
```

I feel like I'm quite close but obviously new to MongoDB! Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use is for comparing a value that is on the document to an input value (which is not saved on the document). If you want to compare two values from the document, use [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/):

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      "$currentTask",
      "$maximumTask"
    ]
  }
},
{
  $inc: {
    currentTask: 1
  }
})
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LsFAsqrZy4u)

This answer will return the document **before** the update. To get the document after the update, use the [options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) like this:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
{$expr: {$lt: ["$currentTask", "$maximumTask"]}},
{$inc: {currentTask: 1}},
{returnNewDocument: 1})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, however this seems to always return the document. Is it possible to only get the document if the increment went through? For example using the `findOneAndUpdate` function?

Comment: Sure. Not a problem. Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but it doesn't work when I run it :(

Comment: Not a bother. Updated the answer to explain this.